# collecting the same items in the object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to sum up the time parts of the object I have specified below in a single list
this is my object;

```
var list = [
{ 'user': 'Tom', time: 270547 },

{ 'user': 'Alex', time: 82081 },

{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 58702 },

{ 'user': 'Tom', time: 53944 },

{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 44938 },

{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 24353 }
]
```

i want convert that code like this,
total time = Sum of the time parts in the top object

```
{ 'user': 'Tom', time: totaltime },

{ 'user': 'Alex', time: totaltime },

{ 'user': 'Bob', time: totaltime}
```

how can i do like this
thats my all code

```
let data = await db
.all()
.filter(x => x.ID.startsWith(`total`))
.sort(function (a, b) {
return JSON.parse(b.data).total - JSON.parse(a.data).total;
});
var list = []
var i = 0;
for (i in data) {
liste.push({
user: client.users.cache.get(data[i].ID.split(":")[1]).username,
time: JSON.parse(data[i].data).total
}) 
}
```

Comment: please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: i updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce and check [what is reduce?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var list = [
   { 'user': 'Tom', time: 270547 },
   { 'user': 'Alex', time: 82081 },
   { 'user': 'Bob', time: 58702 },
   { 'user': 'Tom', time: 53944 },
   { 'user': 'Bob', time: 44938 },
   { 'user': 'Bob', time: 24353 }
]
var result = [];
list.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.user]) {
    res[value.user] = { user: value.user, time: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.user])
  }
  res[value.user].time += value.time;
  return res;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and then convert the object back to an array using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) if you actually need an array rather than an object:

```js
const list = [
  { user: 'Tom', time: 270547 },
  { user: 'Alex', time: 82081 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 58702 },
  { user: 'Tom', time: 53944 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 44938 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 24353 }
];

const results = list.reduce((result, entry) => {
  const userResult = result[entry.user];
  
  if (userResult) {
    userResult.time +=entry.time;
  } else {
    // We use the spread operator here to avoid mutating the original
    // entries inside `list`:
    result[entry.user] = { ...entry };
  }
  
  return result;
}, { });

console.log('As object =', results);

console.log('As array =', Object.values(results));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

Alternatively, if you sort the list, you can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to get the results in an array straight away, without creating any intermediate objects:

```js
const list = [
  { user: 'Tom', time: 270547 },
  { user: 'Alex', time: 82081 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 58702 },
  { user: 'Tom', time: 53944 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 44938 },
  { user: 'Bob', time: 24353 }
];

// First, sort the list by user to make sure you process all entries
// for the same user consecutively:

list.sort((a, b) => a.user.localeCompare(b.user));

const results = [];

let currentEntry = {};

list.forEach((entry) => {
  if (currentEntry.user !== entry.user) {
    // We use the spread operator here to create a copy of the object,
    // to avoid changing the original one:
    currentEntry = { ...entry };
    
    // Add each user to the array only once:
    results.push(currentEntry);
  } else {
    currentEntry.time += entry.time;
  }
}, {});

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to loop over your list, every time you meet a new name, you'll create a new object for that name and add the time to that object and store it somewhere. The next time you find the same name you add the new time to the old time until done, then you simply need to collect all objects into an array again.

Here is some code for one way of doing this:

```
function timeByName(list) {
    const names = {};
    list.forEach(item => {
        const previous = names[item.name] || { name: item.name, time: 0 };
        previous.time += item.time;
        names[item.name] = previous;
    });

    return Object.values(names) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript reduce method. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is more information.

```js
let list = [
{ 'user': 'Tom', time: 270547 },
{ 'user': 'Alex', time: 82081 },
{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 58702 },
{ 'user': 'Tom', time: 53944 },
{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 44938 },
{ 'user': 'Bob', time: 24353 }
]

const usersTime = list.reduce((acc, {user,time}) => {
acc[user] = (acc[user] || 0) + parseInt(time,10) ;
return acc
},{});
const result = Object.keys(usersTime).map(user=>({user:user,time:usersTime[user]}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't generate the output the OP is looking for.  This sums all times.  The OP wants to sum times by name.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for your advice. I edited the snippet and I think is correct now.